# C# Declare a Static List

Tags: c#, list, static, uwp

I am using a Static List to store some values, the idea is declare the list, then a button in page 1 adds some values, then a button in page 2 adds some more values, to do this I am triying declare it in each page but the list is newly created:

> public static List _songlist = new List(); in each page.

Can you help me?, how I can declare the static list then have the same list with the values in all the pages?

```
public static List<Song> _songlist = new List<Song>();

public class Song
{
private string _name;
public string name
{
get { return _name; }
set { SetProperty(ref _name, value); }
}
private string _artist;
public string artist
{
get { return _artist; }
set { SetProperty(ref _artist, value); }
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is the problem? Where do you declare the  `_songlist` ? If it is in, say `mainWindow`, you can access it as `mainWindow._songlist`..

Comment: You need to move the 'new' so it is only perform once in the code (new List()),

Comment: You say put only one with new and the rest with "public static List<string> _lista = List<string>();" it show error: "Non-invocable member 'List<T>' cannot be used like a method."

Comment: "Static" means only one instance. If "I am triying declare it in each page but the list is newly created" then on every page load, you just overwrote what the last page did. Page 1 creates a list and adds values to it. On Page 2, you declared a brand new list, so the list from Page 1 is now gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you, you want an Application wide static list.

Why not create a new file called `ApplicationServices.cs` and put a static class inside of it with a static `List<Song>`

```
public static class ApplicationServices{
      public static List<Song> Songs {get; set;}
}
```

This way you can access it everywhere by calling `ApplicationServices.Songs`

Comment: Thank you, I am studing your comment now.

Comment: @Julius if this works for you please don't forget to checkmark and upvote. Thanks